# How to show the json data

Tags: http, label, tableview, titanium-mobile

In my Titanium weather project I want to parse json data and show the data in my project,  but I'm not able to. I am trying so hard but keep failing.

Here is my code, what is the problem? Please anybody help me.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgorundColor: '#000',
    title: 'My Weather App'
});

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var data = [];

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function () {

        alert("success!");
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.observation_location.length; i++) {

            //data.push({"country":json.observation_location[i].country,"city":json.observation_location[i].city});
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                height: 60,
                //filter:observation_location[i].
            });
            var countryLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: json.observation_location[i].country,
                height: 'auto',
                left: 10,
                top: 5,
            });
            var cityLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: json.observation_location[i].city,
                height: 'auto',
                left: 15,

            });

            row.add(countryLabel);
            row.add(cityLabel);
            data.push(row);
        }

        tableview.setData(data);

    },
    onerror: function () {
        alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
    }
    //timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/02e5dd8c34e3e657/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Dhaka,Bangladesh.json");
xhr.send();

win.add(tableview);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON returned doesn't appear to be an array of data.  You can check this by running the application in debug and setting a breakpoint right after the json variable is assigned.  You can then navigate the data returned.  Though there is a lot of information returned, none of it in particular looks like an array so I removed your loop.  In addition, observation_location is inside current_observation, so you would access it by **json.observation_location.current_observation**.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgorundColor: '#000',
    title: 'My Weather App'
});

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var data = [];

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function () {

        alert("success!");
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //for (var i = 0; i < json.observation_location.length; i++) {

            //data.push({"country":json.observation_location[i].country,"city":json.observation_location[i].city});
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                height: 60,
                //filter:observation_location[i].
            });
            var countryLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: json.current_observation.observation_location.country, //json.observation_location[i].country,
                height: 'auto',
                left: 10,
                top: 5,
            });
            var cityLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: json.current_observation.observation_location.city, //json.observation_location[i].city,
                height: 'auto',
                left: 15,

            });

            row.add(countryLabel);
            row.add(cityLabel);
            data.push(row);
        //}

        tableview.setData(data);

    },
    onerror: function () {
        alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
    }
    //timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/02e5dd8c34e3e657/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Dhaka,Bangladesh.json");
xhr.send();

win.add(tableview);
win.open();
```